# Is it possible to see when i will be ranking up in competitive matchmaking?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Im stuck on silver 3 and winning a lot of matches in competitive matchmaking, iv won about 10 in a row and still in silver 3, is there anyway to see when i will be ranking up and how close i am to ranking up, is there some sort of rank points that i am able to view for myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everyone's ELO score is hidden and cannot be viewed.

Based on speculation, not ranking up while having a win streak can be caused by several reasons:

- You only won against lower ELO-based opponents due to lobby up with lower ELO-based mates or due to bad luck
- You are in the bottom EP-area of your rank and need just more points to rank up
- You recently lost a lot of EP's, which leads to the point mentioned right above
- You queued up with a cheater, he was detected and your recent wins have been nullified
- If there is a K-Factor involved in Valve's algorithm, yours is pretty low

The only indication that you are close to ranking up is if you are queueing up alone, look in the end of the match at your teammates and enemies ranks. If they are mostly one rank above you, you are close to rank up. Although this only happens if you are 1 to 3 games away of ranking up.